# How to get reference to mapper in type converter?

Tags: c#, automapper

Is there a way to access a mapper in type converter. Right now, which is bad, I have to do ObjectFactory.GetInstance to get instance of the session from StructureMap. If I was able to get reference to mapper I could use that to get instance of the entity, like mapper.Map and avoid having static method call in type converter.

So this code

```
 public class AddBaseProductCommandConverter : TypeConverter<AddBaseProductService.AddBaseProduct, AddBaseProductCommand>
    {
        protected override AddBaseProductCommand ConvertCore(AddBaseProductService.AddBaseProduct source)
        {
            var session = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<ISession>("PRDProd");
            var marketingPlan = session.Get<MarketingPlan>(source.BaseProductInfo.MarketingPlanId);
            var baseProductTemplate = session.Get<BaseProductTemplate>(source.BaseProductInfo.Code);
            var benefitPeriod = session.Get<BenefitPeriod>(source.BaseProductInfo.BenefitPeriodCode);
            var insuranceServiceType = session.Get<InsuranceServiceType>(source.BaseProductInfo.ServiceTypeCode);

            var command = new AddBaseProductCommand
            {
                MarketingPlan = marketingPlan,
                BaseProductTemplate = baseProductTemplate,
                BenefitPeriod = benefitPeriod,
                InsuranceServiceType = insuranceServiceType
            };

            return command;
        }
    }
```

Could be rewritten like this (I build a map for each persistent type that NHIbernate recognizes, during configuration phase)

```
 public class AddBaseProductCommandConverter : TypeConverter<AddBaseProductService.AddBaseProduct, AddBaseProductCommand>
    {
        protected override AddBaseProductCommand ConvertCore(AddBaseProductService.AddBaseProduct source)
        {
            var mapper = ????

var  marketingPlan = mapper.Map<int,MarketingPlan(source.BaseProductInfo.MarketingPlanId);
            var baseProductTemplate = mapper.Map<string,BaseProductTemplate>(source.BaseProductInfo.Code);
... and so on ...
           return command;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `ITypeConverter` instead of `TypeConverter`, then use the argument `context` to get the mapper using `context.Engine.Mapper`, something like this:

```
public class AddBaseProductCommandConverter : ITypeConverter<AddBaseProductService.AddBaseProduct, AddBaseProductCommand>
{
    public AddBaseProductCommand Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (context.SourceValue == null || !(context.SourceValue is AddBaseProductService.AddBaseProduct))
            throw new AutoMapperMappingException();

        var mapper = context.Engine.Mapper;

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this who is using a a more recent version of Automapper (e.g. 8), the `ITypeConverter` and `ResolutionContext` definitions have changed a bit from the previous answer.  You can access the mapper through the `Mapper` member on the context.  e.g.

```
public class AddBaseProductCommandConverter : ITypeConverter<AddBaseProductService.AddBaseProduct, AddBaseProductCommand>
{
    public AddBaseProductCommand Convert(AddBaseProductService.AddBaseProduct source, AddBaseProductCommand destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var mapper = context.Mapper;

        ...
    }
}
```